# Is two-way binding possible between nuxt.js and nova service? (ara-nuxtjs-demo)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, micro-frontend, ara

I'm testing demo: https://github.com/marconi1992/ara-nuxtjs-demo

Is there a way to dynamically change the props in the "nova component" when changing props to Nuxt.js?
Or some other way for dynamic communication between Nuxt.js and Nova components?

Nuxt component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <nova name="Vue" :data="{ count: count }" />
        <a @click="count = count + 1">+1</a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Nova from 'nova-vue-bridge'

export default {
  components: { Nova },
  data: function () {
    return {
      count: 1
    }
  },
  head: {
    script: [
      { src: 'http://localhost:8081/client.js' },
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```

Nova component (Vue):

```
<template>
  <h1>{{count}}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['count']
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can do that by using the concept of refs. Just provide a ref to the nova component. Using that ref you can change the data inside of the nova component.